# RSpec controller spec passes without corresponding instance variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, factory-bot

I wrote a spec to test the instance variable @vendors in the index action of my vendors controller.  If I remove @vendors from the vendors controller the spec still passes.  Any ideas as to why assigns(:vendors) would pass if @vendors doesn't exists in the controller.  Heres my code:

***Vendors Controller***

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    # @vendors = Vendor.all
  end

end
```

***Vendors Controller Spec***

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'ruby-debug'

describe VendorsController do
  login_user

  before(:each) do
    @vendor = Factory(:vendor)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    before(:each) do
      @ability.can :read, Vendor
    end
    it "assigns all vendors to @vendors" do
      get :index
      assigns(:vendors).should == [@vendor]
    end
    it "should render the index template" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
      response.code.should eq("200")
      response.should render_template("index")
    end
  end
end
```

***Vendors Factory***

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :vendor do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) { |n| "Test#{n}" }
    f.sequence(:address) { |n| "000 Test#{n} drive, Hampton" }
    f.state "Virginia"
    f.zip "00000"
    f.sequence(:telephone) { |n| "000-000-000#{n}" }
    f.sequence(:poc) { |n| "Test#{n}" }
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because load_and_authorize_resource actually loads and authorizes.

So your code is unnecessary.

You could change with authorize_resource, thus the spec will fail.

Comment: That fixed it.  I forgot about cancan loading the resources.  Thanks for you help.